# Посоветуйте шаблон проектирования

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

```
 public class Order
{
    public final static int FIXED_AMOUNT_COMMISION = 1;
    public final static int FIXED_PERCENT_COMMISION = 2;

    private BigDecimal quantity, price;
    private int commisionType;

    public Order(BigDecimal quantity, BigDecimal price, int commisionType)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.commisionType = commisionType;
    }

    public BigDecimal getQuantity(){return quantity;}
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {return price;}

    public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity)
    {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal calculateCommesion(){
        switch (commisionType){
            case FIXED_AMOUNT_COMMISION:
                return new BigDecimal("200.00");
            case FIXED_PERCENT_COMMISION:
                return getQuantity().multiply(getPrice()).multiply(new BigDecimal(0.10));
        }
        return  new BigDecimal(0.00);
    }
    //other data and methods
}
```

Нужно поменять дизайн кода, так чтобы отвечал следующим критериям:

1. легко добавлять новые типы комиссионных и их исчисления в системе без изменения класса Order
2. возможность изменить тип комиссионной данного заказа после его создания;
3. добавить 3-ий вид комиссионной по следующим критериям:

   - если количество больше данного порога (задается каждой инстации    отдельно) комиссионная равна 50,00;
   - в противном случае комиссионная равна 100,00;
4. Убрать все твердо заданные числа и заменить их параметрами.

Comment: можно передавать функцию-калькулятор комиссии для каждого созданного объекта например

Comment: Strategy вам в помощь

Comment: Подскажите как реализовать первый пункт при помощи патерна Стратегия, при уловии что в пункте 4 нам надо будет упрать твордо заданые числа...

Comment: @АлександрДерменжи, все критерии (в том числе и числовые) - в стратегию. Как именно вы будете хранить их внутри -- зависит от реализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Order {

    private BigDecimal quantity, price;

    public Order(BigDecimal quantity, BigDecimal price) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public BigDecimal calculateCommesion(Strategy strategy) {
        return strategy.calculate(this);
    }
}

public interface Strategy {
    BigDecimal calculate(Order order);
} 

public class StrategyFixedAmount implements Strategy {

    private final BigDecimal value;

    public StrategyFixedAmount(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal calculate(Order order) {
        return value;
    }
}

public class StrategyFixedPercent implements Strategy {
    private final BigDecimal percent;

    public StrategyFixedPercent(BigDecimal percent) {
        this.percent = percent;
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal calculate(Order order) {
        return order.getQuantity().multiply(order.getPrice()).multiply(percent);
    }
}

public class StrategyThirdType implements Strategy {
    private final BigDecimal porog;
    private final BigDecimal before;
    private final BigDecimal after;

    public StrategyThirdType(BigDecimal porog, BigDecimal before, BigDecimal after) {
        this.porog = porog;
        this.before = before;
        this.after = after;
   }


    @Override
    public BigDecimal calculate(Order order) {
        return order.getQuantity().compareTo(porog) > 0 ? after : before;
    }
}

public class TestOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Order order1 = new Order(new BigDecimal(10), new BigDecimal(100));
        Order order2 = new Order(new BigDecimal(100), new BigDecimal(300));
        Order order3 = new Order(new BigDecimal(40), new BigDecimal(700));

        Strategy strategy1 = new StrategyFixedAmount(new BigDecimal(200));
        Strategy strategy2 = new StrategyFixedPercent(new BigDecimal(0.1));
        Strategy strategy3 = new StrategyThirdType(new BigDecimal(200), new BigDecimal(50), new BigDecimal(100));

        System.out.println(order1.calculateCommesion(strategy1));
        System.out.println(order1.calculateCommesion(strategy2));
        System.out.println(order1.calculateCommesion(strategy3));

        System.out.println(order2.calculateCommesion(strategy1));
        System.out.println(order2.calculateCommesion(strategy2));
        System.out.println(order2.calculateCommesion(strategy3));

        System.out.println(order3.calculateCommesion(strategy1));
        System.out.println(order3.calculateCommesion(strategy2));
        System.out.println(order3.calculateCommesion(strategy3));
    }
}
```